# After installing composer: "The drush command X could not be found"

Tags: 7, drush, composer

**Edit: re-wrote intro paragraph to highlight the installation of composer - I suspect composer may have broken drush.**

I want to test out elastic search with D7.  I used drush to install a fresh D7 install, then views, elasticsearch_connector, libraries.  At that point Watchdog indicated that I was missing the elasticsearch-php library.

I tried to follow [Elasticsearch's instructions on getting this library](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_installation_2.html) and installed composer:

```
/sites/mysite $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /sites/aarp/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
/sites/mysite $ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/
```

I added an alias for composer to my `~/.profile`.  I have not been able to use any drush commands since (see below).  I have since discovered that [composer can be used to install drush](http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-7-using-composer) so now I suspect this is the root of my trouble.

```
/sites/mysite $ drush en composer_manager -y
composer_manager was not found.                                                                                                                                        [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                                                                [ok]
composer_manager
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
cProject composer_manager (7.x-1.7) downloaded to sites/all/modules/composer_manager.                                                                                   [success]
dThe following extensions will be enabled: composer_manager
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
composer_manager was enabled successfully.                                                                                                                             [ok]
One or more extensions have dependencies managed by Composer.
Update packages managed by Composer? (y/n): y
Download and install the Drush Composer extension? (y/n): y
Directory /Users/mmutrux/.drush exists, but is not writable. Please check directory permissions.                                                                       [error]
Project composer (8.x-1.x-dev) could not be downloaded to /Users/mmutrux/.drush/composer.                                                                              [error]
The drush command 'composer' could not be found.                                                                                                                       [error]
/sites/mysite $ chgrp _www /Users/m
macadmin/ mmutrux/  
/sites/mysite $ chgrp _www /Users/mmutrux/.drush/
chgrp: you are not a member of group _www
/sites/mysite $ chgrp _www /Users/mmutrux/.drush/
/sites/mysite $ chmod 777 /Users/mmutrux/.drush/
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/mmutrux/.drush/: Operation not permitted
/sites/mysite $ sudo chmod 777 /Users/mmutrux/.drush/
Password:
/sites/mysite $ drush en composer_manager -y
The drush command 'en composer_manager' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.        [error]
/sites/mysite $ drush cache-clear drush
The drush command 'cache-clear drush' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.          [error]
```

Where'd my drush go??

**Edit: added in response to comments**

```
/sites/mysite $ which drush
/opt/local/bin/drush
/sites/mysite $ drush --version
The drush command 'version' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.                    [error]
/sites/mysite $ sudo drush --version
The drush command 'version' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.                    [error]
/sites/mysite $ drush --version -v
Initialized Drupal 7.35-dev root directory at /sites/aarp                                                                                                                 [notice]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default                                                                                                                          [notice]
The drush command 'version' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.                    [error]
```

Comment: Sounds like permission issues but it would probably be easier to just start over...just for kicks what does "drush --version" and/or "which drush" say?

Comment: @burnsjeremy Good idea. Looks like drush can't even find it's own version.

Comment: What did "which drush" output? And did the "drush --version" just error out? Try adding a -v (verbose tag) to get some more helpful output.

Comment: @burnsjeremy See edit at the end of my post.

Comment: Is the /opt a personal preference? Normally "which drush" gives /usr/local/bin/drush

Comment: I assume the difference is due to the mac filesystem (which I'm not too familiar with yet).  I don't even have a `/usr/local/bin`.  See my new update - I suspect composer messed up my drush installation.

Comment: I will start a chat when I get back from lunch, composer probably did but we can debug that or I can help out with installing a fresh drush with the new installation methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20122/discussion-between-burnsjeremy-and-doub1ejack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone but if you do ever run into this issue:

This seemed to be a permissions issue from the beginning, so in chat we:

- Removed the old drush and composer instances.
- Installed Composer
- Downloaded Drush from Github
- Installed dependencies via Composer

Once we had a fresh copy of drush it seems that drush now worked just fine. We had some small issues that came from the machine that was being used.

Answer (score 9):

Being inspired by comment by Free Radical, it works for me even without removing .composer directory:

1. `drush cc all` *outside* the Drupal root directory
2. `drush cc all` *inside* the Drupal root directory

Answer (score 1):

I was bitten by the same problem after trying to install [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) for D7 using this command:

```
drush en composer_manager -y
```

The installation crashed, and after that, drush responded “The drush command X could not be found” for *every* X, including `cc` and `version`.

This is what I did to get it working again:

1. Removed a directory named `.composer` that had been created in my home directory.
2. Did `drush cc all` *outside* of the Drupal root (this now works).
3. Did navigate to the Drupal root, and did `drush cc all` again (this now works).

I haven't done any testing to see if *all* these steps are necessary - just posting it in case it helps someone who wants to recover from this without reinstalling *drush*.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Drupal in a Docker image with [Bowline](https://github.com/davenuman/bowline) I hit the same problem, but the `drush cc all` method didn't work, and I didn't want to trash Bowline's composer installations.

But taking the hints from above, I found that manually deleting the `./.drush/cache` directory in my project root (same level as Bowline's `bin`) fixed drush. I hope that helps someone with the same circumstances.

Comment: This also worked for Travis CI and Drupal TI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner approach...

```
pushd $HOME && drush cc drush && popd
```